# In Azure, what is the best way to set up Authentication that is a simple Uname/Password in, bearer token out flow?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I come from AWS land, and there it's quite simple to set up cognito to manage users and take in a username/password, authenticate it, and return a token.  I'm expecting to send a username and password to an endpoint from postman, and receive a token, nothing more. I've been trying to find an explanation of how to do this simply in Azure and it has not been forthcoming.  Can anyone point me to a good and simple solution?

I've tried using App Service's built in authentication.  It does indeed set up properly and 401 my requests as expected, but I cannot find documentation that clearly states how to get a token to then put my Authorization header to call the endpoints.